# Getting a Array Property as a Single string and not a string[]

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

So im busy on a little project, learning angular/Typescript and something is confusing me..

Im trying to create a login form using the firestore db instead of the Auth side as I need user info associations and it seems redundant to use auth and just create  a user and then find and extract them.

Anyhow. So with the logins Im planning on just using inputs and a button that sends the values to a function with parameters Then check against the users array I get on the onInit()
So:

```
users: User[];

//Nginit(){Fetch users}

Login(userName: string, passWord: string){
const output = this.users.map( x => x.username )
 if(username == output){
   //Do stuff
 }
}
```

But now why despite the map is the output  a String[] and not a string do i have to .toString();

Because I doubt the input field will pass threw a String[] to the login button itll more then likely be a string
so im just a bit confused .

Edit:
**What I ended on:**

```
  login(userName, passWord){    

    const name = this.users.find( x => x.username === userName)
    const pass = this.user.find( x => x.password === passWord)
    if(name && pass){
      this.users.forEach(element => {

        if(element.username = userName){
            this.entry.username = userName;
            this.entry.color = element.color;
        }
        
      });
    }else{
      alert("User Details are incorrect please make sure your username and password is correct");
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const output = this.users.find( x => x.username === username)
 if(output){
   //Do stuff
 }
```

Comment: For clarity sake for anyone els finding this. I changed the parameter variables to stand out more so your answer would just change to (x => x.username === userName)

So your just returning true if both are the same type/values I get it

Answer (score 0):

All map does is to call the given function for each element in the original list and create a list with the results.

The way you wrote it now you are transforming a list of users in a list of user names.

If you want to check if an element is in the result list you can easily do it with `includes`

```
const output = this.users.map( x => x.username )
if(output.includes(username)) {
  //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Hmm so you mean something like this 
 ///this.users being the array
``` if(this.users.includes(username) && this.users.includes(password)){ } ```

Comment: no, the line with the map call should remain unchanged. just use the include in the if condition. you can do it the way @zainhassan posted if you want to do it in a single line.

Comment: Ooh I thought just to check in the actual if thanks for the answer Both answers work for me, I'll just need to determine which is the easiest to expand extracting the user on and ill accept one